# Why is this display alert not working? it worked fine when i tried it in a button Clicked event, but its not working in a Function

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

1 ) Its a weather Api and i want it to display no internet connection when there is no internet connected to the device.

```
        public async void method()
    {
        Indicator.IsRunning = true;
        Weather weather = await GetWeather(nameplace.Text);

        if (weather != null)
        {
            if (weather.message == "city not found")
            {
                 txtLocation.Text = "city not found";
            }
            else
            {
                Location.Text = weather.Title;
                Temperature.Text = weather.Temperature;
                Temperature.Text += "°";
                txtWind.Text = weather.Wind;
                Humidity.Text = weather.Humidity;
                Sunrise.Text = weather.Sunrise;
                Sunset.Text = weather.Sunset;
                double condition = Convert.ToDouble(weather.Condition);
                if (condition >= 0 && condition < 30)
                {
                    Condition.Text = "Clear Sky";
                }
                else if (condition >= 30)
                {
                    Condition.Text = "Cloudy";
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
       await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Sorry ! No internet connection","Ok")`
        }
    }
```

3) // Below in a getservice function i have

```
if (Plugin.Connectivity.CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(QueryString);
```

// pQueryString is the http request

```
            _httpStatusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            if (response == null)
            {
                return "Sorry! No record Found.";
            }
            else if (response != null)
            {
                string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            data = null;
        }
        return data;
```

4) i have return null and put a condition in there so that it can display an alert saying no internet connection

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your async void method messes with the Thread context, and that you end up not calling your code in the ui thread.

You could try this:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
    () => DisplayAlert("Alert", "Sorry ! No internet connection","Ok"));
```

Also it's a bad design to put UI code in your service layer.
Your should call your `DisplayAlert` code in your `ViewModel` not in your service.